# How to pass a configurable parameter to the constructor when using a Provider?

Tags: java, guice

I have recently added a `Throttler` field to a `Server` class that is to be instantiated only if throttling is enabled (this is a config entry), and if so, the max number of requests per sec (another config entry) is to be passed to its constructor.

Here is the code without dependency injection of `Throttler`:

```
public class Server {
    private Config config;
    private Throttler throttler;

    @Inject
    public Server(Config config) {
        this.config = config;

        if (config.isThrottlingEnabled()) {
            int maxServerRequestsPerSec = config.getMaxServerRequestsPerSec();
            throttler = new Throttler(maxServerRequestsPerSec);
        }
    }
}

public class Throttler {
    private int maxRequestsPerSec;

    public Throttler(int maxRequestsPerSec) {
        this.maxRequestsPerSec = maxRequestsPerSec
    }
}
```

Now to inject `Throttler`, I used a `Provider`, since it doesn't always need to be instantiated. But now I am forced to inject `Config` into `Throttler` and let it "configure itself":

```
public class Server {
    private Config config;
    private Provider<Throttler> throttlerProvider;

    @Inject
    public Server(Config config, Provider<Throttler> throttlerProvider) {
        this.config = config;
        this.throttlerProvider = throttlerProvider;

        if (config.isThrottlingEnabled()) {
            this.throttler = throttlerProvider.get();
        }
    }
}

public class Throttler {
    private int maxRequestsPerSec;

    @Inject
    public Throttler(Config config) {
        maxRequestsPerSec = config.getMaxServerRequestsPerSec();
    }
}
```

I don't like this solution because:

1. There is a dependency of an utility class (`Throttler`) to `Config`.
2. `Throttler` is now tied to a specific configuration entry, which means it cannot be used by anything else but `Server`.

I would prefer to somehow inject `maxRequestsPerSec` into the construtor.

Is that possible with Guice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Guice FAQ](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-when-creating-an-object-via-guice) recommends to introduce a factory interface which builds the class with its dependencies and additional parameters passed by the client.

```
public class Throttler {
    ...
    public static class Factory {
        @Inject
        public class Factory(... Throttler dependencies ...) {...}
        public Throttler create(int maxRequestsPerSec) {
            return new Throttler(maxRequestsPerSec /*, injected Throttler dependencies */);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, all the direct dependencies of Throttler remain encapsulated in the Throttler class.

You can also use the [AssistedInject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) extension to reduce the boilerplate code.

Comment: Definitely check out assisted injection, makes your live much easier.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on how you implement the Provider interface and on your application. If the only way to get the maxRequestsPerSec is from the Config,you can do something along these lines:

You could have the specific Provider implementation injected, and have a setter in that. So in your constructor you inject `CustomProvider<Throttler>` (which implements `Provider`), then perform `setMaxRequestsPerSec`, and then use that in the `get` method when instantiating your Throttler.

If you don't want to inject `CustomProvider`, you can instead inject the Provider and then do an `instanceof` check but I think it would be better to inject the CustomProvider.